# VBA - Error shows like "Object variable or With block variable not set "

Tags: vba, excel

Error shows like "Object variable or With block variable not set "

A variable 'Sathish'  should have this type of values "ABC21A". Please suggest me how to declare this variable. Also, this code needs to run 1000 times to fetch data. I didn't have a privilege to access the tool outside from office. So I can't provide the link.

## Please see the below code:

This is Sathish, While run the below code I received error at this area 
(appIE.document.getElementById("__tab_tabFilter").Click   appIE.document.getElementById("filter_ReferenceCode").Value = sathish)

```
Sub macro()
    Dim appIE As Object
    Dim objElement As Object
    Dim Y As Long
    Dim obj As Object
    Dim r As Long, c As Long, t As Long

    Dim objCollection As Object
    Dim eRow As Long

    ' Create InternetExplorer Object
    Set appIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

    With appIE
       appIE.Visible = False
       appIE.navigate "website"

       Do While appIE.Busy Or appIE.ReadyState <> 4
          DoEvents
       Loop

       appIE.Visible = True    
       appIE.document.getElementById("Username").Value = ""
       appIE.document.getElementById("Password").Value = ""
       appIE.document.getElementById("btnSubmit").Click

       Number = Range("A1", Range("A1").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count

       For Y = 1 To Number
           sathish = Cells(Y, 1).Value
           appIE.document.getElementById("__tab_tabFilter").Click
           appIE.document.getElementById("filter_ReferenceCode").Value = sathish    
           appIE.document.getElementById("filter_btnSetFilter").Click

           'Set IE = Nothing          
           Set objCollection = appIE.document.getElementsByTagName("TABLE")

           For t = 10 To (objCollection.Length - 1)
               For r = 0 To (objCollection(t).Rows.Length - 1)
                   eRow = Sheet2.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
                   For c = 0 To (objCollection(t).Rows(r).Cells.Length - 1)
                       ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(2).Cells(eRow, c + 1) = objCollection(t).Rows(r).Cells(c).innerText
                   Next c
               Next r        

               If t = objCollection.Length - 1 Then
                   Cells(eRow + 1, 1) = ""
               End If
           Next t
        Next Y
    End With     
    ' Set IE = Nothing     
End Sub
```

Comment: What type of variable is "sathish"? You haven't declared it. I would always advise using Option Explicit at the top of your code modules to force you to declare every variable.

Comment: Hi,still I' m facing the error from here although I used Option Explicit "appIE.document.getElementById("__tab_tabFilter").Click
           appIE.document.getElementById("filter_ReferenceCode").Value = sathish  " same error object variable or with block variable not set"